# matrix notion of a complex double summation

Tags: matrices, summation

Is it possible convert the left double summation into matirx multiplication in the right?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{M} \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} a_{i, j} [m_{i, j} - m_{i, j+1}]^2  = m^TL^TLm $$
where, $m_{i,j}$ is a $MxN$ length vector rather than a matrix;
then how to present matrix L with $a_{i,j}$?

I know in this one summation case $$\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} a_j [m_j - m_{j+1}]^2=m^TL^TLm ,$$
where, $m_{j}$ is a $Nx1$ vector;
I can solve L as matrix
$$\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc} 
-\sqrt{a_1} & \sqrt{a_1} &  &  &  \\ 
  & -\sqrt{a_2} & \sqrt{a_2} & \ddots &  \\
  & & \ddots & & \\
\end{array} 
\right] .$$

Comment: Have you tried a toy example? Say with $M=2$ and $N=2$, something like that.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I am confused. You have elements $m_{i,j}$ so that $m$ should be a matrix, right? Hence, $m^TL^TLm$ is a matrix as well. Therefore, you can equate both sides of the first  equation, since the LHS is a scalar and the RHS is a matrix. Am I missing something?

Comment: so, $m_{i,j}$ is supposed to be a $MxN$ length vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $L(a_1,\dots,a_N)$ is the matrix you gave for the one summation case using the weigths $a_1,\dots,a_N$.
Moreover, let $m$ be a vector made by $m = [m_1^T,\dots,m_M^T]^T$ where each $m_i = [m_{i,1},\dots,m_{i,N}]^T$ for any $i=1,\dots,M$. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S&:=\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}a_{i,j}(m_{i,j}-m_{i,j+1})^2\\ &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}a_{1,j}(m_{1,j}-m_{1,j+1})^2\right) + \cdots + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}a_{M,j}(m_{M,j}-m_{M,j+1})^2\right)\\
&=S_1+\cdots+S_M
\end{aligned} 
$$
where $S_i := \sum_{j=1}^{N-1}a_{i,j}(m_{i,j}-m_{i,j+1})^2 = m_i^TL_i^TL_im_i$ and $L_i := L(a_{i,1},\dots,a_{i,N})^TL(a_{i,1},\dots,a_{i,N})$ by the one summation identity. Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S&=m_1^TL_1^TL_1m_1+\cdots+m_M^TL_M^TL_Mm_i\\
&=m^TGm
\end{aligned}
$$
with
$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}
L_1^TL_1 & 0 &\cdots& 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots & 0 & L_M^TL_M
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hopefully, I did not messed up anywhere. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Amazing! That's pretty much close to my expects.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: would you like to answer a similar question? I have not gotten any responses since i posted the question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212524/matrixing-double-summation