# matrixing double summation

Tags: matrices, summation

Is it possible convert double summation in the left into matirx multiplication in the right?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N}  [a_{i, j} (m_{i} - m_{j})]^2  = m^TAm ,$$
where, $m = [_1,…,_]^$.
then how to express matrix A with $a_{i,j}$?

this is a similar question link to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209335/matrix-notion-of-a-complex-double-summation).

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: If you want I can write a full answer with more details later, when I have more time. But if you are urged to know the answer, this looks like the quaratic form you obtain from the Laplacian of a weighted graph, with weigths $w_{ij}=a_{ij}^2$. In other words, the matrix $A$ you want might just be a laplacian matrix constructed as here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~satishr/cs270/sp11/rough-notes/Tree-metrics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjqh_CC55DyAhWPA2MBHciSB6MQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw3qvKVeQjEB6Rgob-IdzxV_

Comment: thanks for your response. the lapliacian matrix looks reasonable, but i am still confused about the expression of A. From my understanding, for eq 2 on your reference, the equation should be writen as $$\sum w_{uv}(x_u - x_v) = [x_u, x_b]^T \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc} 
 w_{uv} & -w_{uv} \\ 
 -w_{uv} & w_{uv} \\
\end{array} 
\right] [x_u, x_b] ,$$ where $x_u$ or $x_v$ is the same vector? then is it different with my expection $m^TAm$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$. Then, if $A$ has components $A_{ij}$ given by
$$
A_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-2a_{ij}^2 & \text{if }j\neq j \\
2\sum_{k=1}^N a_{ik}^2 & \text{if }i=j 
\end{array}\right.
$$
it follows that
$$
m^TAm = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2(m_i-m_j)^2
$$

In the following I give a proof. Sorry if it looks complicated. I guess there is a simpler argument as mine without using indices, but I think this procedure might be enough for you. Maybe someone else can provide a simpler proof.

Moreover, as I said in the comments, the matrix $A$ is similar to the Laplacian matrix of a graph where nodes are connected by weights $a_{ij}^2$. The only difference is that in your summation, if $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, the term $a_{ij}^2(m_i-m_j)^2$ appears twice, so that the edge $i\sim j$ is taken into account twice as well. That is the reason for the extra factor of $2$ in the definition of the elements $A_{ij}$.

---

**Proof:**

Lets compute $Am$ first. The $i$-th component of $Am$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\{Am\}_i &= \sum_{j = 1}^N A_{ij}m_j = A_{ii}m_{i}+\sum_{i\neq j} A_{ij}m_j\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}^2m_{i}-\sum_{i\neq j} 2a_{ij}^2m_j = 2\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2(m_i-m_j)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, lets compute $m^TAm$
$$
m^TAm = \sum_{i=1}^N m_i\{Am\}_i = 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j)
$$
Now comes the trick. We will split the last double summation in two identical parts as:
$$
2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j) = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j) + \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j)
$$
And since the index names are arbitrary, just interchange $i$ with $j$ in the second term:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j) = \sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^Na_{ji}^2m_j(m_j-m_i) = -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_j(m_i-m_j)
$$since $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and $(m_j-m_i) = -(m_i-m_j)$. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
m^TAm&=2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j)\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_i(m_i-m_j) -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2m_j(m_i-m_j) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2(m_i-m_j)^2
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Now, for $a_{ij}\neq a_{ji}$ the extension is simple. A similar trick as before (splitting + index renaming) leads to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{ij}^2(m_i-m_j)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{a_{ij}^2+a_{ji}^2}{2}(m_i-m_j)^2 
$$
such that $w_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij}^2+a_{ji}^2}{2}$ comply $w_{ji}=w_{ij}$ and reduces to $w_{ij} = a_{ij}^2$ in the symmetric case. Thus, the same definition of $A$ I gave before works with $w_{ij}$ instead of the terms of the form $a_{ij}^2$.

Hopefully I did not messed up anywhere. Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Marvel! thanks for your comments. $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ is sufficient for my case. It looks correct from my tests.

Comment: Nice! Good luck then!